# How to end a program if the user guesses the secret phrase. My code runs in a never ending loop

Tags: python

So my problem with my code is that I can't figure out how I can check if the correct guesses equal the random Secret Phrase given. Thus I want to check if the user has guessed all the letter in the secret phrase. Basically, my code is running in a never ending loop. I have tried making if statements to check if the guesses from the user equals to the secret phrase but it will not work.

```
#Define a filename
filename = "puzzles.txt".lower()

#Imports
import random
import string

#Open the file and read
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    randomSecretPhrase = (random.choice(lines)) #Choose random phrase from file

    #***Output secret word to screen test***
    print(randomSecretPhrase)

#Initalize        
correct = []
incorrect = []
count = 0

def game():
    for i in randomSecretPhrase:
        if i in correct:
            print(i,end=' ')
        #elif i != ' ':
        elif i in string.ascii_letters:
            print('_',end=' ')
        else :
            print(' ',end=' ')
    print("\n\n")
    print('Number of times guessed: ', count)
    print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')

def guessed_letters():
#Will check the user input to verify valid letter is entered
    while True:
        guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
        if guess in correct or guess in incorrect:
            print("You have already guessed that letter. Please guess again.")
            print(count)
        elif guess.isnumeric():
            print("Please enter only letters not numbers! Guess again.")
        elif len(guess) > 1:
            print("Please enter only one letter at a time. Please guess again.")
        elif len(guess) == 0:
            print("Please enter a letter.")
        elif len(correct) == len(randomSecretPhrase):
             print('You win')
        else:
            break

#Keep track of correct and incorrect guesses
    if guess in randomSecretPhrase:
        correct.append(guess)
        print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
        print("You have guessed correctly!")
        print('\n')

    else:
        print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
        incorrect.append(guess)
        print("You have guessed incorrectly!")
        print('\n')

#Main program
while True:

    #Call game()
    game()
    #Call guessed_letters()
    guessed_letters()
    #Count how many times guesses
    count += 1
    check()






Output Example:
Number of times guessed:  6
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Guess a letter: w
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
You have guessed correctly!


a   c l e a n   s w e e _   


Number of times guessed:  7
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Guess a letter: p
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
You have guessed correctly!


a   c l e a n   s w e e p   


Number of times guessed:  8
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Guess a letter:
```

Comment: if len(correct) == len(randomSecretPhrase):

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```
def check():
    for i in randomSecretPhrase:
        if i not in correct:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Yes something like that but it has to end the program saying "You have won!"

Comment: You can just change the check line in the main while loop to `if check(): print('You have won!')`

Answer (score 0):

Your main program is this:

```
while True:

    #Call game()
    game()
    #Call guessed_letters()
    guessed_letters()
    #Count how many times guesses
    count += 1
    check()
```

which, hopefully clearly, never ends.

You can give them a maximum number of tries like this:

```
while count < 3: #or other maximum

    #Call game()
    game()
    #Call guessed_letters()
    guessed_letters()
    #Count how many times guesses
    count += 1
    check()
```

Of course, you would have to vary this for the length of the phrases.

In order to find out if they guessed ok, you need `guessed_letters` to tell you what its already figured out - if the guess is right or not.
You can changed this to return a value:

```
def guessed_letters():
#Will check the user input to verify valid letter is entered
    while True:
        guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
        if guess in correct or guess in incorrect:
            print("You have already guessed that letter. Please guess again.")
            print(count)
        elif guess.isnumeric():
            print("Please enter only letters not numbers! Guess again.")
        elif len(guess) > 1:
            print("Please enter only one letter at a time. Please guess again.")
        elif len(guess) == 0:
            print("Please enter a letter.")
        elif len(correct) == len(randomSecretPhrase):
             print('You win')
        else:
            break

#Keep track of correct and incorrect guesses
    if guess in randomSecretPhrase:
        correct.append(guess)
        print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
        print("You have guessed correctly!")
        print('\n')
        return True

    else:
        print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
        incorrect.append(guess)
        print("You have guessed incorrectly!")
        print('\n')
        return False
```

Now, you can check in the `while` loop:

```
while True:

    #Call game()
    game()
    #Call guessed_letters()
    if guessed_letters(): #<-- check the return code
        break             #<-- done if correct
    #Count how many times guesses
    count += 1
    check()
```

In order to proclaim "You have won", you need to think about the stopping coniditon.
You will a list, `correct` with the guessed letters. and compare the length of this to the length of the `randomSecretPhrase`, which is a string.
Just on `"sweep"` the letters will be `['s', 'w', 'e', 'p']` when the guess is corrected.

You need to move the check after you collect the new guess and just check the letters are correct:

```
def guessed_letters():
#Will check the user input to verify valid letter is entered
    while True:
        guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
        if guess in correct or guess in incorrect:
            print("You have already guessed that letter. Please guess again.")
            print(count)
        elif guess.isnumeric():
            print("Please enter only letters not numbers! Guess again.")
        elif len(guess) > 1:
            print("Please enter only one letter at a time. Please guess again.")
        elif len(guess) == 0:
            print("Please enter a letter.")
        else:
            break


#Keep track of correct and incorrect guesses
    if guess in randomSecretPhrase:
        correct.append(guess)
        print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
        print("You have guessed correctly!")
        print('\n')

    else:
        print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
        incorrect.append(guess)
        print("You have guessed incorrectly!")
        print('\n')

    if len(correct) == len(set(randomSecretPhrase)):
         print('You win')
         return True
    return False
```

This will count unique letters in the `randomSecretPhrase`, and compare with the `correct` letters after adding the `guess`.

You will find it easier to make small functions and tests these one at a time.
For example, when you read the file lines you include the line ending so need to remove this:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    phrase = (random.choice(lines)) #Choose random phrase from file
    randomSecretPhrase = phrase.strip()
    #***Output secret word to screen test***
    print(randomSecretPhrase)
```

Comment: It seems that when you enter the first guess it seems to end the program immediately.